# can not access closed stream using C# while upload csv file to ftp

Tags: c#, csv, stream

I am working on an application where I need to upload CSV files to an FTP server. I am facing an error mentioned below.

> can not access the closed stream

Here is a code sample

```
public Stream WriteCSV<T>(List<T> content) where T : class
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.WriteRecords(content);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
    return stream;
}

// calling method
var _writeService = new WriteService();
using var stream = _writerService.WriteCSV(partLocatorFiltered.ToList());
var fileUploadPath = $"/input/partslocator042/KE5206205_TEST_CSV.csv";
await _iFtpClientService.SendFileAsync(_options?.FTP, stream, fileUploadPath);
```

I am facing an issue while uploading the CSV stream to the FTP server.

Comment: You can show respect for those who might help you by making the basic effort to ensure your code sample is well-formatted, and not indented way to the right.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn my master I do

Comment: Most stream wrappers take a "leaveOpen" parameter for just this purpose.

Comment: can anybody please let me know what I am doing wrong here